# Azure websites complaining Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles

I'm having headaches with Azure website deployment at the moment, someone help please - it has taken me 2 days trying to figure out what exactly has gone wrong:

The website is ASP.NET MVC using Azure Storage for storing web pages (custom VirtualPathProvider is implemented)

It works perfectly on my local PC however once I deploy it to Azure website, it hangs forever - and when checking the diagnoiss (XXX.scm.azurewebsites.net)  there are full loads of errors complaining "Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE"

This is an Azure websites, nothing related to web roles, there's no reference to RoleEnvironment in my code at all.

Have search throughout Stackoverflow but haven't found an answer,  someone help me out please...

When I look onto the event viewer from Azure's support portal, I find these

Error in the event viewer (surprisingly simple errors):

8400
w3wp
Role environment . INITIALIZING

---

8400
w3wp
Role environment . INITIALED RETURNED. HResult=-2147024891

---

8400
w3wp
Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891

Comment: Can you include the exact errors you are getting? Also, where exactly are you seeing those errors?

Comment: hi I'm seeing this from Azure App Event View from via the azure portalL

Comment: event details is really simple:

8400
w3wp
Role environment . INITIALIZING

and then following with another event log:
8400
w3wp
Role environment . INITIALED RETURNED. HResult=-2147024891

Then the error:
8400
w3wp
Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891

Comment: Can you share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Hi David, I've shortened the real site url to: http://goo.gl/NrD7ew    you'll be able to get the url once you visit it,  thanks

Comment: hi David - have created a dummy site name:   dummysite2016   hope that helps. thanks

Comment: "Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE" sounds like you app is a "Cloud Service" project, can you double check your code? i don`t think you can deploy a cloud service application onto Azure App Service directly.

Comment: Hi Xiaomin... Triple checked...  I think some code must be broken during the process causing the "FAILED TO INITIALIZE"  but I can't understand why it works locally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your VM, I see that it is constantly compiling views (I believe the same things all the time). My guess is that there is some issue in your `VirtualPathProvider` implementation that is disabling the caching. e.g. do you have a proper implementation of `GetCacheKey`?

You may want to try remote debugging to debug your VPP logic, which might give some clues.

Comment: Thank you for saving me from another sleepless night!....  I knew something was wrong with the VPP -- and I checked a million times till you drove me to GetCacheKey!  it turned out i had a wrong method inside which keeps generating Guid.New(), I simply removed the referenced method and used virtual path with it's generic GUID and that fixed everything....  should have asked on stckoverflow 2 days earlier... thank you!