# Azure websites complaining Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE on startup

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

my question is similar to [Azure websites complaining Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226474/azure-webistes-complaining-role-environment-failed-to-initialize?rq=1)

Error that I see in the Azure  App Service Support Event Viewer:

"
9236
w3wp
Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891
"

It happens every single time on startup of the website. Other than that - website functions just fine. Except, randomly (it might take 10-30 minutes) it stops with "The application was terminated." (i see this error through azure application logs). I am not sure if these two things are related, but I am trying to first fix the "FAILED TO INITIALIZE" issue.

I don't have references to RoleEnvironment anywhere in my code (some users on StackOverflow mentioned that this might be an issue).

I read through many posts but none seem to work for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue was the reference to "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration". Once this assembly is not referenced anymore - no more errors on startup. Apparently, this assembly is designed to be used with Cloud Services, not Web Applications.

Answer (score 3):

Check your Web.Config for references to  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics” or “Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime"

If you have these , they are designed for use with Cloud services and not required or needed with Web Apps.

Comment: thank you, this was helpful in tracking down the actual problem.