# Azure App service Role environment Failed to Initialize

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

there are multiple warnings in event viewer

```
  w3wp Role environment . INITIALIZING 

  w3wp Role environment .INITIALED RETURNED. HResult=-2147024891    

  w3wp Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891
```

followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495505/azure-websites-complaining-role-environment-failed-to-initialize-on-startup) and removed all references to WindowsAzure.Configuration and checked Remove All additional files during publishing but I still see these warnings in logs

Comment: According to you description, we couldn’t directly find the reason why shows this error.Could you please post more information about your web application’s references? Do you use custom VirtualPathProvider?
If you could explain more about your web application, it will be more easily for us to find the reason.I guess you maybe use the package for the could service in your web application. I suggest you could also check your Web.Config for references to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics” or “Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime".

Comment: found the issue, it was reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime and the dependent assembly entry for the same library in web.config. No more warnings after removing this dll... Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I'm glad to hear you have solved the issue. I will write a reply in this thread, please mark as answer to help other people who faces the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could check the Web.Config for references to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics” or “Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.

Since these are designed for could services and not for the app services, so you will face these error.